# Preloading lazy route with canLoad applied

Tags: angular, routes

The docs says i cannot use the two features together https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#canload-blocks-preload

What i want to achieve is to lazy load routes if the user is authorized to visit the route.

Comment: Then don't use `PreloadAllModules strategy`

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Well, that is why i asked it because i want to use both :F

Comment: If this is a feature request I think you should raise it at the Github site for Angular, Cheers!!

Answer (score 7):

Using both is not logical. Using `canLoad` tells angular you want to prevent loading the module until the guard is resolved. Therefore preloading respects this and does not preload this module.

Why would you do this? Well, let's say you have an admin module or some other sensitive module that you don't want to be loaded and potentially inspected until authentication is passed. Preventing preloading here is great.

If you really want to protect your route but also preload it then use `canActivate` instead of `canLoad`.

Comment: What if I want to NOT allow user to download package which is only for authorized users (lets say admin module), AND customly preload lazyLoad children modules after loggin in on admin?

Comment: Without canLoad guard person who knows path to admin, can manually enter url and load admin's code.

Answer (score 2):

you might wanna use **CanActivate** guard instead of **CanLoad**.
that way you will still be able to set preloadingStrategy to PreloadAllModules and it effectively preload the content of the 'lazy loaded feature' module even if 
canActivate returns false.

Answer (score 2):

For this goal you should use custom preloading strategy and move canLoad check to some service.
So, for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthPreloadStrategyService implements PreloadingStrategy {

    public constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    public preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        return this.authService.canLoad(route) ? fn() : Observable.of(null);
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Preload won't be called at all if canLoad handler exist.**